# Separate Application and system folder for multiple or single site on separate servers :Code Igniter

Tags: php, file, codeigniter, directory

I need some code igniter experts to put there valuable time and efforts on this.

```
$system_path = '/home/user14/Music/system';
$application_folder = '/home/user14/Music/application';
```

**It runs fantastic when I hit the website url.**

What if we consider the below case ,
for security purpose wants to separate the system folder
from current server to another server leaving the application folder and index.php on the current server,Or vice versa .
just consider separating these two folders ie. moving any 1 from one server to another server .
**example**

```
$system_path = 'www.oscarjewels.com/system';

$application_folder = '/home/user14/Music/application'; //app on the same server.
```

Now these returns error I have tried debugging but really nothing worked for me .

Enabled remote_url in php.ini. with no positive response from the site.

Answer (score 0):

Use https:// in system path and then try.

```
$system_path = 'https://www.oscarjewels.com/system';

$application_folder = '/home/user14/Music/application'; //app on the same server
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include remote files you need to make sure that `allow_url_include` is enabled in your php.ini.  You will also need to append the protocol to the system path.  So depending on what protocol you want to use it could be

```
$system_path = 'http://www.oscarjewels.com/system';
```

or

```
$system_path = 'ftp://ftp.www.oscarjewels.com/system';
```

However I would discourage you from including remote files like this because it, **insecure** it will have a **performance hit** and it could make your application **unreliable**.

Comment: same error .
could you try eddting the same lines at your end on your CG project.

Comment: Warning: require_once(http://www.oscarjewels.com/system/core/CodeIgniter.php): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error in /opt/lampp/htdocs/php/cg/index.php on line 222

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'http://www.oscarjewels.com/system/core/CodeIgniter.php' (include_path='.:/opt/lampp/lib/php') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/php/cg/index.php on line 222